# My PHP source code is not executing properly with Apache2 on WSL, always need to restart to apply changes

Tags: php, apache2, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL for PHP development. Since one day, every time I changed my source code and checked on the local address, the change didn't apply until I restart the apache.

I googled about it for a while, nothing came up with this problem.

I reinstalled the PHP and apache2 but nothing changed.

Which file should I look for this problem?
Please could anyone guess what causes this problem?

Below are my PHP version and apache information.

```sh
$ php -v
PHP Warning:  Module 'exif' already loaded in Unknown on line 0 
PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 (cli) (built: May 26 2020 13:09:11) ( NTS ) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group 
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies 
with Zend OPcache v7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.6, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

```sh
$ apache2 -v    
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)     
Server built:   2020-08-12T21:33:25
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found out the WSL version was 1, so I made it upgrade to WSL2.
The problem solved.